# How to write File name to a label

Tags: file, actionlistener, jlabel, jfilechooser

I would like to have the name of the chosen file from JFileChooser from the JMenuItem and show it in a JLabel when a JCheckBoxMenuItem is checked. I am able to choose the file but can't have its name. The important bits of the code is shown below,

```
private JFileChooser fc;
private JLabel currentDocPanel;
public JCheckBoxMenuItem viewOpt;

public String getFileName() {
    String str = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
    return str;
}
private class ActionEventHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if (e.getSource() == viewOpt) {
            if (currentDocPanel.isVisible()) {
                currentDocPanel = new JLabel(getFileName());
                currentDocPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
                add(currentDocPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply..I tried the code you provided but did not see the file name on the label. I changed my code a bit and I am able to see the text within the label, but the problem is that I can only see it when I hold the window and expand it with mouse. I call this function in the actionPerformed when JCheckBoxMenuItem is clicked. This is what I did;

```
 public void getFileName() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("getFileName");
    try {
        File getfile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        boolean check = getfile.exists();
        if (check) {
            System.out.println("File Name: " + getfile.getName()); //to check
            String nameToLabel = "File Name: " + getfile.getName();
            currentDocPanel = new JLabel(nameToLabel);
            //currentDocPanel.setText(String.valueOf(fc.getSelectedFile()));
            currentDocPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            add(currentDocPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple:

```
currentDocPanel.setText(String.valueOf(Your_JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
```

Should work. Here, I just get the selectedFile of the JFC and transform the output as String.

Comment: I tried the code you provided but did not see the file name on the label. I changed my code a bit and I am able to see the text but the problem is that I can only see the label when I hold the window and expand it with mouse. This is what I did;